# How to reuse type constraints, and parameters, of a parent function in inner functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to refactor this tutorial exercise answer below, but I'm having trouble.

First, I would like to use the `arr` parameter declared in the outer function in the inner functions. I assume it would be in scope, just as it would in Javascript.

So this:

```hs
maxIndex :: (Ix sourceIndexType, Ord sourceElementType) => Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceIndexType
maxIndex arr = findLargestIndexOfElement arr (findLargestElement arr)
    where
        findLargestElement :: (Ix sourceIndexType, Ord sourceElementType) => Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceElementType
        findLargestElement arr = maximum $ elems arr
        findLargestIndexOfElement :: (Ix sourceIndexType, Ord sourceElementType) => Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceElementType -> sourceIndexType
        findLargestIndexOfElement arr element = fst $ foldr1 (\(itemk,itemv) (acck, accv) -> if element==itemv then (itemk,itemv) else (acck,accv)) (assocs arr)
```

becomes

```hs
maxIndex :: (Ix sourceIndexType, Ord sourceElementType) => Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceIndexType
maxIndex arr = findLargestIndexOfElement arr findLargestElement 
    where
        findLargestElement :: sourceElementType
        findLargestElement = maximum $ elems arr
        findLargestIndexOfElement :: sourceElementType -> sourceIndexType
        findLargestIndexOfElement element = fst $ foldr1 (\(itemk,itemv) (acck, accv) -> if element==itemv then (itemk,itemv) else (acck,accv)) (assocs arr)
```

but Haskell doesn't seem to be able to access any higher level definitions from an inner function. Am I right in my understanding? Haskell isn't able to do this?

The next simplification I want to do is reuse my parameters' type constraints. So the original code would become:

```hs
maxIndex :: (Ix sourceIndexType, Ord sourceElementType) => Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceIndexType
maxIndex arr = findLargestIndexOfElement arr (findLargestElement arr)
    where
        findLargestElement :: Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceElementType
        findLargestElement arr = maximum $ elems arr
        findLargestIndexOfElement :: Array sourceIndexType sourceElementType -> sourceElementType -> sourceIndexType
        findLargestIndexOfElement arr element = fst $ foldr1 (\(itemk,itemv) (acck, accv) -> if element==itemv then (itemk,itemv) else (acck,accv)) (assocs arr)
```

but this change also makes Haskell error. It completely ignores that `sourceIndexType` in any of the functions is the same type. I may as well call them all `paramType1` `paramType2` `blue58`. How do I make Haskell understand I'm using the same type for each??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell type variables have by default only a single type-signature as their scope, even when `-XScopedTypeVariables` is enabled. To make the whole function *to which this is the signature* as the scope, you need to explicitly quantify the type variables.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

maxIndex :: ∀ sIt sEt. (Ix sIt, Ord sEt) => Array sIt sEt -> sIt
maxIndex arr = findLargestIndexOfElement arr largestElement 
  where
    largestElement :: sEt
    largestElement = maximum $ elems arr
    findLargestIndexOfElement :: sEt -> sIt
    findLargestIndexOfElement element
        = fst $ foldr1 (\(itemk,itemv) (acck, accv)
                          -> if element==itemv then (itemk,itemv)
                                               else (acck,accv))
                       (assocs arr)
```

Comment: Thank you, this code doesn't seem to compile though

Comment: Well, so what's the error?

Comment: If it's something unicode related, use `forall` instead of the upside-down A